# How to get Lego Mindstorms EV3 expansion set (45560) programmes in Scratch

Tags: ev3, technic, mindstorms, programming, scratch

I bought recently Mindstorms EV3 expansion set (45560) and found out that the available programs are written in old LabView-style programming language: https://le-www-live-s.legocdn.com/sc/media/files/ev3-program-descriptions/ev3-program-description-elephant-e20fc1fce44f0596fd83d090346e5c30.pdf .

Since the Lego released new version of programming environment - EV3 Classroom which supports Scratch - the old Labview-style language is no longer supported.

The official Lego site doesn't provide Scratch versions of the expansion set robot programms. Neither does the EV3 Classroom.

Is there any way to obtain Scratch versions of programs for expansion set robots?